# get unique values with distinct function in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data as below

```
library(tibble)
df <- tibble(ID = c(100000L, 100000L, 100000L, 100000L, 100001L, 100001L, 100001L, 100001L, 100002L, 100002L, 100002L, 100002L, 100003L, 100003L, 100003L), subject_result2 = c("OTHERPassedTerm1", "OTHERPassedTerm1", "OTHERPassedTerm1", "MATHPassedTerm1", "OTHERPassedTerm1", "OTHERPassedTerm1", "OTHERPassedTerm1", "OTHERFailedTerm1", "OTHERPassedTerm1", "OTHERPassedTerm1", "MATHPassedTerm1", "MATHFailedTerm1", "OTHERPassedTerm1", "MATHPassedTerm1", "OTHERPassedTerm1"))
```

```r
# A tibble: 15 x 2
       ID subject_result2 
    <int> <chr>           
 1 100000 OTHERPassedTerm1
 2 100000 OTHERPassedTerm1
 3 100000 OTHERPassedTerm1
 4 100000 MATHPassedTerm1 
 5 100001 OTHERPassedTerm1
 6 100001 OTHERPassedTerm1
 7 100001 OTHERPassedTerm1
 8 100001 OTHERFailedTerm1
 9 100002 OTHERPassedTerm1
10 100002 OTHERPassedTerm1
11 100002 MATHPassedTerm1 
12 100002 MATHFailedTerm1 
13 100003 OTHERPassedTerm1
14 100003 MATHPassedTerm1 
15 100003 OTHERPassedTerm1
```

I want to get a unique `subject_result2` based on each`ID`. Something like below but this code does not work

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 distinct(subject_result2)
```

Could you fix my problem? thanks

desired result:

```r
#   <int> <chr>           
#1 100000 OTHERPassedTerm1
#2 100000 MATHPassedTerm1 
#3 100001 OTHERPassedTerm1
#4 100001 OTHERFailedTerm1
#5 100002 OTHERPassedTerm1
#6 100002 MATHPassedTerm1 
#7 100002 MATHFailedTerm1 
#8 100003 OTHERPassedTerm1
#9 100003 MATHPassedTerm1
```

Comment: Your code seems to work fine to me.

Comment: Same as above, what is your expected output?

Comment: What do you mean by "this code does not work"? What error do you get? If the issue is that other columns also disappear, then you need to specify how we need to decide which rows to leave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that you could do is to count instances of combinations of ID and subject_result2.

```
new_df <- df %>%
          group_by(ID, subject_result2) %>%
          summarise(id = n()) %>%distinct() %>%
          select(-id)


new_df
```

Answer (score 3):

You would only need to do

```
distinct(df)
# A tibble: 9 x 2
#      ID subject_result2 
#   <int> <chr>           
#1 100000 OTHERPassedTerm1
#2 100000 MATHPassedTerm1 
#3 100001 OTHERPassedTerm1
#4 100001 OTHERFailedTerm1
#5 100002 OTHERPassedTerm1
#6 100002 MATHPassedTerm1 
#7 100002 MATHFailedTerm1 
#8 100003 OTHERPassedTerm1
#9 100003 MATHPassedTerm1
```

Comment: thank you but in my actual data I have more columns so using only distinct does not help

Comment: @Cina Then please give an example that mimics your problem.